# Allow only single type of mark in string

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I'm trying to figure out, how to allow only single type of mark in string. For example if string `inputStr` contains different marks:

```
string inputStr = "hello, how are you? ~ say something: what's up? hi... tell me. what?! ok: so,";
```

this way:

```
string outputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"[^\w\s]", "");
```

In result I will get `outputStr` without any marks:

```
hello how are you say something whatsup hi tell me what ok so
```

with desired result, I want keep only single specific colon `":"` mark in `outputStr`:

```
hello how are you say something: whatsup hi tell me what ok: so
```

Any guide, advice or example would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You could use following.

```
[^\w\s:]
```

Code

```
string outputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"[^\w\s:]", "");
```

If you want to have a custom function, you can do the following so that you can reuse the method with different characters.

```
 public static string ExtendedReplace(string sourceString, char charToRetain)
 {
      return Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"[^\w\s{charToRetain}]", "");
 }
```

Now you could use as following.

```
string inputStr = "hello, how are you? ~ say something: what's up? hi... tell me. what?! ok: so";
string outputStr = ExtendedReplace(inputStr, ':');
```